# What algorithm used in interp1d function in scipy.interpolate

Tags: python, scipy, cubic-spline

So i was writing a python program for my numerical course, and I had to code a cubic spline program. So i implement the formula for cubic spline given in books like [Numerical methods by Chapra and canale](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0073401064) and [Numerical mathematics by chenny and kincaid](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1133103715).

so my data is

```
x=[1.0,3.0,4.0,7.0]
y=[1.5,4.5,9.0,25.5]
```

Using this data and applying cubic spline I get for `x=1.5` , `y=1.79122340426`

While using this same data but using the scipy function gives:

```
  >>> scipy.interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')(1.5)
array(1.265624999999932)
```

So, why is that difference in result? It is obvious that they are not using the same formula.
What is the cubic spline formula used in that scipy function? Is it a natural cubic spline formula or something improved?
Note: The value 1.2656 is more acurate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: @ev-br in the comments for this answer provided an important correction to my answer. In fact interp1D spline is not FITPACK based. Check the comments for the link provided by @ev-br.

The Scipy functions for curve fitting are based on FITPACK. Try seeing the documentation on the functions you are using and you'll be able to see a "References" chapter where something like this will appear:

```
Notes
-----
See splev for evaluation of the spline and its derivatives. Uses the
FORTRAN routine curfit from FITPACK.
If provided, knots `t` must satisfy the Schoenberg-Whitney conditions,
i.e., there must be a subset of data points ``x[j]`` such that
``t[j] < x[j] < t[j+k+1]``, for ``j=0, 1,...,n-k-2``.
References
----------
Based on algorithms described in [1]_, [2]_, [3]_, and [4]_:
.. [1] P. Dierckx, "An algorithm for smoothing, differentiation and
   integration of experimental data using spline functions",
   J.Comp.Appl.Maths 1 (1975) 165-184.
.. [2] P. Dierckx, "A fast algorithm for smoothing data on a rectangular
   grid while using spline functions", SIAM J.Numer.Anal. 19 (1982)
   1286-1304.
.. [3] P. Dierckx, "An improved algorithm for curve fitting with spline
   functions", report tw54, Dept. Computer Science,K.U. Leuven, 1981.
.. [4] P. Dierckx, "Curve and surface fitting with splines", Monographs on
   Numerical Analysis, Oxford University Press, 1993.
```

These references in particular where taken from the source of [fitpack.py](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/fitpack.py) on the function "splrep". If you need to do a very thorough comparison between your algorithm and the spline from interp1D just go to the docs:

[scipy.interpolate.interp1d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy-interpolate-interp1d)

And you'll see a link called [[source]](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v0.16.1/scipy/interpolate/interpolate.py#L306) right after the definition of the name of the function (so: scipy.interpolate.interp1D       [source]). Remember that there's a lot of routine handlers on these functions so be patient while navigating the source.

Comment: Generally correct, `splrep/splev` and `UnivariateSpline` uses FITPACK, but `interp1d` is not.

Comment: If it does not than they chose some strange names for their sub-modules because inside the interp1D source you can clearly see the call for "splmake" (if interpolation is spline) which in turn has B = _fitpack._bsplmat(order, xk). I would interpret this as using FITPACK.

Comment: No, `_bspldismat` is not using FITPACK the Dierckx fortran library :-).

Comment: Here's the source: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/src/__fitpack.h#L1287

Comment: Well in that case I'm at a loss. I truly thought scipy splines where, generically speaking, re-implementations or calls to the FITPACK routines. I'll defer to more informed opinion. I'll edit my answer to call into attention your commentary. Sorry for the misinterpretation.

Comment: yes, it's a bit of a mess, sadly. Most of them are, as you rightly say (BTW, +1 from me). `interp1d` is an odd one out.

Comment: Same here, and better safe than sorry. I'm not sure it's relevant to the poster but I would hate to think someone took some wrong assumptions based on my answer. Thanks for the insight.