# Unexpected results from scipy.interpolate.Rbf

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation

I am getting some errors when interpolating with RBF. Here is an example in 1D. I think that it has to do with how close my y values are to each other. Is there any fix for this?

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf, interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0.77639752, 0.8136646, 0.85093168, 0.88819876, 0.92546584, 0.96273292, 1.])
y = np.array([0.97119742, 0.98089758, 0.98937066, 0.99540737, 0.99917735, 1., 0.99779049])
xi = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),1000)

fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,y,'ko', label='Raw Data')

#RBF
rbfi = Rbf(x,y, function='linear')
plt.plot(xi,rbfi(xi), label='RBF (linear)')

rbfi = Rbf(x,y, function='cubic')
plt.plot(xi,rbfi(xi), label='RBF (cubic)')

#1D
f = interp1d(x,y, kind='cubic')
plt.plot(xi,f(xi), label='Interp1D (cubic)')


plt.plot(x,y,'ko', label=None)
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.tight_layout()

plt.savefig('RBFTest.png')
```

[image]

Comment: what were you expecting?

Comment: I guess I thought that the RBF cubic would match the interp1D cubic and not be all wild like it is.

Comment: Mathematically [radial basis interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_interpolation) is not the same as [spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation) no matter the order of the spline.

Answer (score 5):

Indeed, when implemented properly, RBF interpolation using the [polyharmonic spline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyharmonic_spline) r^3 in 1D coincides with the **natural** cubic spline, and is a "smoothest" interpolant.

Unfortunately, the scipy.interpolate.Rbf, despite the name, does not appear to be a correct implementation of the RBF methods known from the approximation theory. The error is around [the line](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/interpolate/rbf.py)

```
self.nodes = linalg.solve(self.A, self.di)
```

They forgot the (linear) polynomial term in the construction of the polyharmonic RBF! The system should have been [(2)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyharmonic_spline).

Now, one shouldn't trust `interp1d` blindly either. [What algorithm used in interp1d function in scipy.interpolate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088340/what-algorithm-used-in-interp1d-function-in-scipy-interpolate) suggests that it may not be using **natural** cubic spline but a different condition. No mentioning of it in the help page: one needs to go into the python source, and I'm afraid of what we will find there.

> Is there a fix for this?

If it's a serious work, make your own implementation of the RBF interpolation algorithm. Or, if you want to try a different implementation in python, there is apparently one from the University of Michigan: https://rbf.readthedocs.io. If you do, could you post your findings here? If not, you've already did a good service by demonstrating an important SciPy error -- thank you!

Answer (score 0):

[scipy.interpolate.Rbf](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.Rbf.html)

> This class is considered legacy and will no longer receive updates.
> This could also mean it will be removed in future SciPy versions. Rbf
> is legacy code, for new usage please use RBFInterpolator instead.

use [scipy.interpolate.RBFInterpolator](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.12.0/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.RBFInterpolator.html)

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf, interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.array([0.77639752, 0.8136646, 0.85093168, 0.88819876, 0.92546584, 0.96273292, 1.])
y = np.array([0.97119742, 0.98089758, 0.98937066, 0.99540737, 0.99917735, 1., 0.99779049])
xi = np.linspace(min(x),max(x),1000)

fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,y,'ko', label='Raw Data')

#RBF linear
rbfi = Rbf(x,y, function='linear')
plt.plot(xi,rbfi(xi), label='RBF (linear)')

#1D
f = interp1d(x,y, kind='cubic')
plt.plot(xi,f(xi), label='Interp1D (cubic)')

plt.plot(x,y,'ko', label=None)
plt.grid()
plt.legend()

#RBF cubic
from scipy.interpolate import RBFInterpolator
rbi =  RBFInterpolator(x[:, np.newaxis],y[:, np.newaxis], kernel= 'cubic' )   # radial basis function interpolator instance
fi= rbi(xi[:, np.newaxis])       # interpolated values
plt.plot(xi, fi, label='RBF_Interpolator (cubic)')
plt.legend()

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image]