# What is the difference between Makima interpolation method from Matlab and scipy.interpolate.interp1d?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, interpolation, scipy-optimize

I want interpolate two 1D array (X and y) with negative and positive values with X contain 1000 negative and positive values. I compared results with Matlab Makima and python scipy interpolate 1D but results are not matching for same input. Why?

Comment: Why would they have to? Best share specifics, and we might be able to offer advice

Comment: You may find this question useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088340/what-algorithm-used-in-interp1d-function-in-scipy-interpolate

Answer (score 3):

The **makima** algorithm implemented in Matlab is a modification of **akima** implemented in scipy. In fact, *makima* stands for *modified Akima piecewise cubic Hermite interpolation*. Therefore, they are two different methods that are likely to provide different results depending on the input data, there is no reason to expect the exact same interpolation. You can find a very detailed explanation about how Matlab modified this method in their blog: [Makima piecewise cubic interpolation](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2019/04/29/makima-piecewise-cubic-interpolation/). For posterity, I'm also adding the link for the archived version of this post from [webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230322160943/https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2019/04/29/makima-piecewise-cubic-interpolation/).

The `scipy.interpolation.interp1d` on the other hand is completely unrelated with either akima or makima methods, read through this other [SO question & answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36088340/what-algorithm-used-in-interp1d-function-in-scipy-interpolate).

Depending on the application, both methods can present the same degree of deviations when compared with the real data, see the paper for example:
[E. L. Dan, M. Dînşoreanu and R. C. Mureşan, "Accuracy of Six Interpolation Methods Applied on Pupil Diameter Data," 2020 IEEE International Conference on Automation, Quality and Testing, Robotics (AQTR), Cluj-Napoca, Romania, 2020, pp. 1-5, doi: 10.1109/AQTR49680.2020.9129915.](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9129915)